# Select a column by name with angular datatables not working

Tags: angularjs, datatables

using angular datatables, I need select a column by name.
I have read datatables documentation in https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns() but I have no success.

In my code below,  I have tried:

```
oTable.column('id')
```

and

```
oTable.column('id:name')
```

But, they are not working.

```
$scope.search = function(query) {
 var oTable = $scope.dtInstance.DataTable;
 //oTable.column('id:name').search($scope.busca.query).draw() ; doesn't works 
 oTable.column('id').search($scope.busca.query).draw() ; //doesn't works 
}  

$scope.dtColumns=[
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id', 'Pront'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('nome', 'Nome').withOption('searchable', false),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('endereco', 'Endereco').notSortable().withOption('searchable', false),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('cidade', 'Cidade').notSortable().withOption('searchable', false),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('cpf', 'CPF').notSortable().withOption('searchable', false),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('telres', 'Telefone').notSortable().withOption('searchable', false),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('email', 'E-Mail').notSortable().withOption('searchable', false),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withTitle('Opçoes').notSortable().withOption('searchable', false)
            .renderWith(actionsHtml)
            ];
```

Comment: are you trying to select data from a single column you select ?

Comment: Hi, Yes, I have a select with some fieldnames. I´d like to search a database after the user choice a field and enter a text into input box. I can´t use a index.

Comment: My real code to search will be: oTable.column($scope.busca.selected).search(busca.query).draw() ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *must* explicitly give the column a [**`name`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.name) in order to make the `:name` selector to work :

```
$scope.dtColumns = [       
  DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('name').withOption('name','name').withTitle('name'),
  DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('position').withOption('name','position').withTitle('position')
];
```

Now you can do for example :

```
$scope.dtInstance.DataTable.column('position:name').search('acc').draw();
```

See it working here -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/bLNM5Qu9kFX0A5fLdfPZ?p=preview**